# Credit card number format for American express

Tags: android, format, credit-card

In my android app, I have this format `xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx` 
for credit card number but when I insert AMEX with 15 digits I want it to be shown as `xxxx xxxx xxxx 1234` Instead, I get `xxxx xxxx xxx1 234`.
How do I fix this?

I'm using this code:

```
textCardNumber.setText("Card Number: " + mActivity.maskedAccountNumber.replaceAll("(.{4})(?!$)", "$1 "));
```

Comment: You should add the code you're using to display the number.

Comment: I did just now, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a simple replace function which expects numbers of length a multiple of 4. You could just improve your formatting algorithm of course. But the most simple solution would be to assure the length of the input string.

In your specific case you could just left pad the input with an `x` for AMEX

```
String maskedAccountNumber = mActivity.maskedAccountNumber;
if (maskedAccountNumber.length() == 15)
    maskedAccountNumber = "x" + maskedAccountNumber;
textCardNumber.setText("Card Number: " + maskedAccountNumber.replaceAll("(.{4})(?!$)", "$1 "));
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to just use -

```
String acc = mActivity.maskedAccountNumber;
textCardNumber.setText("Card Number: xxxx xxxx xxxx " + acc.substring(acc.length() - 4));
```